# E/ConstraintSet: transitionEasing syntax error syntax:transitionEasing="cubic(1.0,0.5,0.0,0.6)" or [standard, accelerate, decelerate, linear]

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-motionlayout

Below error log shown in logcat

```
2020-07-25 20:55:37.354 25907-25907/com.hindcaller E/ConstraintSet: transitionEasing syntax error syntax:transitionEasing="cubic(1.0,0.5,0.0,0.6)" or [standard, accelerate, decelerate, linear]
2020-07-25 20:55:37.397 25907-25907/com.hindcaller E/ConstraintSet: transitionEasing syntax error syntax:transitionEasing="cubic(1.0,0.5,0.0,0.6)" or [standard, accelerate, decelerate, linear]
2020-07-25 20:55:37.434 25907-25907/com.hindcaller E/ConstraintSet: transitionEasing syntax error syntax:transitionEasing="cubic(1.0,0.5,0.0,0.6)" or [standard, accelerate, decelerate, linear]
2020-07-25 20:55:37.514 25907-25907/com.hindcaller I/Choreographer: Skipped 2 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

I have integrated `androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout`.

Depedencies:
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta8'